# passar input ao executar bat

Tags: python, cmd, scrapy

Boa tarde, tenho um .bat pra executar um arquivo python, o mesmo precisa receber uma entrada, só que não estou conseguindo rodar esse input ao rodar o .bat, alguém sabe como se faz?

segue informações do bat:

```
cd C:\Users\Jonathan Pereira\Desktop\ProjetoIruan\Robos\Aranhas\spiders
scrapy crawl imprensa_Nacional -o imprensa_Nacional.csv -s CSV_DELIMITER=";"
```

segue trecho do código que receberá o input:

```
name = 'imprensa_Nacional'
data = input("Insira uma data: ")
start_urls = ['http://www.imprensanacional.gov.br/leiturajornal?data='+data+'&secao=dou3']
```

Comment: Tente colocar aspas no caminho "C:\Users\Jonathan Pereira\Desktop\ProjetoIruan\Robos\Aranhas\spiders"

Comment: Não funcionou fazer com ""

Comment: Você esta tentando executar como administrador?

Comment: Qual o erro que apresenta ao rodar o bat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Considere 3 coisas:**

**1)** Python não é minha praia

**2)** Se entendi a pergunta

**3)** Se está correto: **os.environ['_data'] = 'data'**

**4)** [Nesse link](https://gist.github.com/brunogama/3056519)  se o mais correto é:

```
       import os  
       name = os.environ.get(_name)
       data = os.environ.get(_data)
 start_urls = os.environ.get(_start_urls)
```

Já fiz algumas vezes uns intercambios de variáveis entre os bats e Fortran.
Acho q tens q adicionar algumas linhas no script/python para ele ler os itens 
processado no input do bat, o que esta comentado no código aqui publicao.

```
@echo off & mode 60,9 & color 0a && setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

break off && set "_cnt=0"& call :_banner_screen

for /l %%l in (1 2 60) do (

    ping -n 1 127.0.0.0 2>nul >nul && cls & echo/!_double_line!

     if %%l neq 60 ( 

         echo/!_underl:~-%%l!&& echo/!_banner:~-%%l!&& echo/!_underl:~-%%l!
         echo/ & echo/ &echo/!_double_line!

        ) else ( 

         echo/!_underl:~-%%l!&& echo/!_banner!&& echo/!_underl:~-%%l!

        )

)

set /p "_input_data= Insira uma data no formato 'DD/MM/AAAA:"

for /f %%c in ('cmd /u /c set /p "=%_input_data:"= %"^<nul^|find /v /c ""') do call set /a _cnt=%%c + 0

if "!_input_data:~0,2!" leq "0" set _error=on
if "!_input_data:~0,2!" gtr "31" set _error=on

if "!_input_data:~3,2!" leq "0" set _error=on
if "!_input_data:~3,2!" gtr "12" set _error=on

if "!_input_data:~6,4!" leq "2002" set _error=on
if "!_input_data:~6,4!" gtr "!date:~6,4!" set _error=on

if not "!_cnt!" equ "10" (

        echo/& echo/ # E R R O : Data informada esta errada: !_input_data!

        goto :_eof

        ) else if /i "!_error!"=="on" (

        echo/& echo/ # E R R O : Data informada esta errada: !_input_data!

        ) 

         echo/!_input_data!| findstr /l /c:"\/" && set _input_data=!_input_data:/=-!
         echo/!_input_data!| findstr /l /c:"\\\" && set _input_data=!_input_data:/=-!

        )

)

set _data=!_input_data!
set _name=imprensa_Nacional
set _start_urls=[http://www.imprensanacional.gov.br/leiturajornal^?data=!_data!^&secao^=dou3]

cls && mode 82,9  &&  echo/!data! & echo/!name! & echo/!start_urls! 

echo/  No script python, adicione esses itens: 
echo/ ----------------------------------------
echo/ os.environ['_data'] = 'data'
echo/ os.environ['_name'] = 'name'
echo/ os.environ['_start_urls'] = 'start_urls'

timeout /t 10 >nul

if exist "C:\Users\Jonathan Pereira\Desktop\ProjetoIruan\Robos\Aranhas\spiders\scrapy.*" (

     pusd "C:\Users\Jonathan Pereira\Desktop\ProjetoIruan\Robos\Aranhas\spiders"

     .\scrapy crawl imprensa_Nacional -o imprensa_Nacional.csv -s CSV_DELIMITER=";"

     popd 

    )    

goto :_eof

:_banner_screen

(

set _double_line=^


set _double_line=!_double_line!^!_double_line!
set "_underl= _________________________________________________________"
set _banner=^
 __________* I M P R E N S A * N A C I O N A L *__________

break on && exit /b

)

:_eof
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, no final de contas não foi necessário implementar nada dentro do código, pois a função que eu criei dentro do arquivo já efetuava esse processamento :) Obrigado pelo ensinamento.